# How does “continue" work in this code?

Tags: c, loops, continue

```
while ( fgets(eqvline, 1024, eqvfile) != NULL ) {

    eqvline[strlen(eqvline)-1] = '\0';

    if (!strcmp (eqvline, "$SIGNALMAP")) {
        start_store_mask = 1;
        continue;
    }

    if (!strcmp (eqvline, "$SIGNALMAPEND")) {
        _num_mask_pins = i;
        sim_inform ( sim, "[vTPSim] Total of %d pins found in equivalent file.\n", _num_mask_pins);
        //return;
        start_store_mask = 0;
    }
}
```

Can you explain how the `continue;` in this code actually works? When the `continue;` is executed, where does the code jump to? Again compare `eqvline` that read the new line? Then when will this code `if (!strcmp (eqvline, "$SIGNALMAPEND")) {` be called?

Comment: when continue is called The rest of the statements in the body are ignored, and execution resumes at the top of the loop with the evaluation of the loop's test(fgets in your case).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler
Thx for the correction.Sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 3):

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
>   nearest enclosing do, for, or while statement in which it appears,
>   bypassing any remaining statements in the do, for, or while statement
>   body.

in your code, after `continue;` is executed, the condition for the while loop is checked immediately.

If the condition is satisfied, control enters inside the loop. First

```
 eqvline[strlen(eqvline)-1] = '\0';
```

is executed.

Then, the statement

```
 if (!strcmp (eqvline, "$SIGNALMAP"))
```

is executed.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. `continue` jumps to the beginning of the loop, i. e. first the condition will be tested (because the `while` construct tests **before** execution, unlike `do-while`), so what you will be executed immediately after `continue` is

```
fgets(eqvline, 1024, eqvfile) != NULL
```

then, depending on the value of this expression,

```
eqvline[strlen(eqvline)-1] = '\0';
```

or the first statement after the loop body.

Comment: Is it worth noting that if the code was a `for` loop, then `continue` would continue with the `reinitialization` code in `for (initialization; condition; reinitialization)`?